# How do I use wordpress to enable a website owner to update my custom HTML?

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

I am coding the website linked below. I want to set it up so that my client can update basic areas of the site (using Wordpress) without going into the code. I installed Wordpress in the Kualo hosting service, but I can't find any tutorials that show me how to enable my client to make updates to this page. If, for example, my client wants to change the menu item at he top of the page to say "DOCUMENTS" instead of "RESOURCES", how would they do that? I want to keep my custom-made html but allow the basic text components of the site to be modifiable by my client via the wordpress interface. Any guidance would be appreciated!

http://layouthuprising.org/LAYU.html